# Target Array Value Directly After Selected One

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm really sorry for I am aware similar questions have already been asked, but whenever I try to do it myself, none seem to apply or work. Basically when a user clicks on one of the elements, I am trying to get the following variables:

- *the id of the selected element*
- *an array with all of the values prior to selected + selected one*
- **an array with all of the values post-selected (selected not included)**
- **the id of the element directly following the selected one**

Thanks to your help in different posts, I have so far managed to complete the first two ones (in italic), but am unable to achieve the other two.
Would anyone know how to do so please? Thank you all in advance for your help!!

jQuery:

```
var days = ['#monday','#tuesday','#wednesday','#thursday','#friday','#saturday','#sunday'];

$('.days').on('click', function() {
  var day = '#'+this.id;
  var index = days.indexOf(day)+1;
  var prev = days.slice(0, index);
  var next = days.slice(index);
  var above = days[index];
});
```

Comment: Just use `dayIds[dayAfterPos]` no need to use `.value` or Are you looking for `$(dayIds[dayAfterPos]).val();`?

Comment: `$(this).attr('id');` is absurd and counter-productive. use -> `this.id`

Comment: `dayIds[dayAfterPos].value` <-- Fails because daysIds is an array of strings

Comment: You have a **typo**: `new dayIds = new`..  should be `var dayIds =`

Comment: Hi everyone, thank you all for your super quick and helpful responses. Basically this is just a silly sample of jquery code for I am trying to learn how to select all the different parts of an array looking to import that onto a future little project with a real purpose for the collected values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should look more like this (though I really don't understand your code logic):

```
var dayIds = ['monday','tuesday','wednesday','thursday','friday','saturday','sunday'];

$('.days').on('click', function() {
  //get selected element id
  var dayId = this.id;

  //find selected position in array and delete all values after
  var dayPos = dayIds.indexOf(dayId);
  var daysBelow = dayIds.slice(0, dayPos + 1;

  //find position of item directly after selected and get value
  var dayAfterPos = dayIds.indexOf(dayId) + 1;
  var dayAfter = dayIds[dayAfterPos]; //(not working)

  //only keep values following selected one
  ...

  console.log(floorsBelow, floorId);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @vsync as your code looks much cleaner and neat, but it's the other two values I am unable to figure out how to get them (get the value of the item following the clicked one, and get an array that only has the values that follow the clicked one)

Comment: why do you insist of adding `#` to each array item? I'm puzzled

Comment: Sorry @vsync, that surely has to do with my complete lack of experience. When I return things and link them to other HTML elements, I just found it easier and less likely to forget to add it at a later stage when required.

Comment: @lVlVP - so which of your variables now doesn't work? and define "not working" please

Comment: All good @vsync, thanks a mil. I've just updated my code with the functional version as I had mistakenly used `day` on the last three instead of `index`. It all works fine now. As for everyone else, thank you so much for all of your help!

Comment: @lVlVP you new code looks a lot like my answer and I see you've learned a lot from it and the comments, so how come the *other* answer was marked as **the** answer and not mine? I'm just wondering the logic here

Comment: I did not mean to upset you or anyone else. I've corrected it, so apologies for that and thanks for your help once again @vsync

Answer (score 0):

This is how you need to slicing the array. I'm not sure all the requirements you have so I have just taken out a snippet to demonstrate how you can get your values.

```
var dayIds = new Array('#monday','#tuesday','#wednesday','#thursday','#friday','#saturday','#sunday');

const current = '#thursday';
const currentIndex = dayIds.indexOf(current)+1;

const prev = dayIds.slice(0, currentIndex);

const next = dayIds.slice(currentIndex);

console.log(current); //#thursday
console.log(prev); //[ '#monday', '#tuesday', '#wednesday', '#thursday' ]
console.log(next); // [ '#friday', '#saturday', '#sunday' ]
```

EDIT:

Added `newVar` to contain next value

```
var dayIds = new Array('#monday','#tuesday','#wednesday','#thursday','#friday','#saturday','#sunday');

const current = '#thursday';
const currentIndex = dayIds.indexOf(current)+1;

const prev = dayIds.slice(0, currentIndex);

const next = dayIds.slice(currentIndex);

const newVar = dayIds[currentIndex];

console.log(current); //#thursday
console.log(prev); //[ '#monday', '#tuesday', '#wednesday', '#thursday' ]
console.log(next); // [ '#friday', '#saturday', '#sunday' ]
console.log(newVar); // #friday
```

Comment: That's amazing @AdityaParab, thank you so much for that. But how would you also give the value directly following the clicked day (which in your example would be 'friday') to a new var?

Comment: It's simple `const newVar = dayIds[currentIndex]; // #friday`. Checkout updated answer.

Comment: I've updated your jquery code with some light alterations to hopefully make it more automated, but it still doesn't appear to work. The `floor` and `index` values appear to be correct, but `prev` returns an empty array, `next` returns the full array and `above` is undefined. Any ideas as per what I did wrong? thank you once again @AdityaParab

Comment: Nevermind my last comment @AdityaParab, I just realised that I should have used `index` on the last three rather than `day`. Once I changed it, all worked perfect. Thank you ever so much for all of your help!!